# SyncAdapter vs JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-syncadapter, android-jobscheduler

Excluding the fact that `JobScheduler` only supports API > 21 - are `JobSchedulers` designed to fully replace `SyncAdapters`? Or does `SyncAdapter` contain any functionality lacking by `JobScheduler`?

My use case is syncing an RSS feed every couple of hours. This is doable with   a JobScheduler - right?

Comment: I would recommend this blog https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/choosing-the-right-background-scheduler-in-android/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say `JobScheduler` is not a direct substitution for `SyncAdapter`, which has a much more specialized purpose (transferring data between the device and a server). `JobScheduler`, on the other hand, serves to schedule tasks to be executed at some point of time in future - just like [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) - but with a broader potential.

By the way, there's an attempt to [backport](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat) `JobScheduler`.

Answer (score 5):

> SyncAdapter
>
> The framework continues to provide the SyncAdapter class for managing tasks that sync data between the device and a server. Sync adapters are designed specifically for syncing data between a device and the cloud; you should only use them for this type of task. Sync adapters are more complex to implement than the libraries and APIs mentioned above, because they require at least a fake authenticator and content provider implementation. For these reasons, you typically should not create a sync adapter just to sync data to the cloud in the background. Wherever possible, you should instead use JobScheduler, Firebase JobDispatcher, or GCM Network Manager .
>
> In Android N (API level 24), the SyncManager sits on top of the JobScheduler. You should only use the SyncAdapter class if you require the additional functionality that it provides.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html